# Maximum Likelihood Estimation density not defined at one value due to point mass

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, density-function, maximum-likelihood

I have a density which is defined on $[0,1)$. On 1 it is not because there is a positive probability of attaining the value 1. Can I still use Maximum Likelihood to estimate the parameters?

For example I have a density with parameter $p$ such that the probability of $\mathbb{P}[X=1]=p$ and on $[0,1)$ it is equally distributed.

My idea was that I can just sort of combine the MLE approaches of discrete / continuous  variables:
$$
\log \prod_{i=1}^n (p 1_{x_i=1}+ \dfrac{1}{1-p}1_{x_i \neq 1})
$$
I am not quite sure whether this is correct because I am mixing up the lebesgue and the counting measure as far as I understand. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: @OliverDíaz No. I meant it that way. It is not the Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: You can frame this as MLE by picking a reference measure $\mu$ so that your sample distribution has density with respect to $\mu$. Here you could consider $\mu = \delta_1 + \nu$, where $\nu$ is the uniform measure on $[0, 1]$. Then your $X$ has density $f(x \mid p) = p I(x = 1) + \frac{1}{1 - p}I(0 \leq x < 1)$, and you can do MLE has usual. But I feel that the choice of $\mu$ was rather arbitrary, and it can affect your mle result.